# Detect if an IP is in the range of Amazon EC2 ips

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

I'm making research about bad bots, especially those making unfair clicks on adds. Detecting if a request comes from a Amazon EC2 instance might be a good idea.

Is there a way to have the list of Amazon IP ranges and update this list ?  Is it reproducible with other VPS providers ?

Tip : is it a good idea ?

Comment: What kind of bots, and what kind of request? Most "good" web crawlers will include their name in their HTTP User-Agent string.

Comment: It's about bad bots that makes unfair clicks on ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list of AWS Public IP Address ranges: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701